# Pantone Color Bridge vs CMYK Color Guide

Tags: cmyk, color-conversion, pantone

1. **Color Bridge Coated vs CMYK Coated** What is difference in CMYK colors from *Pantone Color Bridge* with colors from *Pantone CMYK Color Guide*? What does the CMYK color simulation mean in *Pantone Color Bridge*? Why CMYK color from *Pantone Color Bridge* is called **Pantone 1234 CP** and the same CMYK color from *Pantone CMYK Color Guide* is called differently - **Pantone P 000-0 C**?
2. **How should I search the color in the Pantone Guide?** For example, I selected Pantone 2190 C color that is the first color on the page in *Pantone Color Bridge*. Now, if I want to find any matching color I should only search the colors horizontally (only in the first row) or all colors from all rows (what it is difficult comparing the first color with the last on the other page)? At first glance, the colors in the rows have similar saturation so match together very well.
3. Gray and black CMYK colors from *Pantone Color Bridge* are not tones of K (0-100% K) but mix of 4 process colors. When I want to use any black Pantone color I have several "black" colors with admixture of red, blue or green color. Is a good idea to buy *Pantone CMYK Color Guide* for matching gray and black color? When I design a logo I can make the text gray (C0 M0 Y0 K80) and primary color select from Pantone colors, right?

Answer (score 1):

Pantone is a company that makes color books. Adobe programs have many of the books in their swatch libraries. A color may seem similar in one book to a color in another book, and that's because the colors on screen seem similar but in all likelihood will be different if a printer uses those Pantone swatches.

> What is difference in CMYK colors from Pantone Color Bridge with colors from Pantone CMYK Color Guide?

Do you mean the CMYK equivalent values of the `Pantone Color Bridge` swatches compared to the `Pantone CMYK Color Guide` values? If so, the CMYK values may be the same or similar, but the printing process can vary.

> What does the CMYK color simulation mean in Pantone Color Bridge? Why CMYK color from Pantone Color Bridge is called Pantone 1234 CP and the same CMYK color from Pantone CMYK Color Guide is called differently - Pantone P 000-0 C?

Each book has a different naming convention for each swatch to determine what book the swatch belongs to. I'm not sure what pattern they follow, but there likely is one that has something to do with the printing method, matte vs. glossy and other factors.

> When I want to use any black Pantone color I have several "black" colors with admixture of red, blue or green color.

In printing, there's process black (C0 M0 Y0 K100) and rich black (check out [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_black)). Process is more "gray" (although still very dark), and is typically used for text. Rich black uses much more ink and is usually saved for assets that really need a dark, deep black.

`A typical rich black mixture might be 100% black, 50% of each of the other three inks. Other percentages are used to achieve specific results, for example 100% black with 70% cyan (C), 35% magenta (M), and 40% yellow (Y) is used to achieve "cool" black. "Warm Black" is 35%C, 60%M, 60%Y, and 100%K`

[Rich Black on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_black)

> When I design a logo I can make the text gray (C0 M0 Y0 K80) and primary color select from Pantone colors, right?

That seems like a great strategy!

Comment: **Never** use 100C100M100Y100K as a "rich black". Not ever. Just saying... `:)` This is a 2016 question, so chances are the user has moved on. But still, ink limits matter.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'll edit my answer. I didn't know that. Adobe programs must do some sort of color correction when exporting. Luckily, I don't have to deal with that too much and I can let the printers help me!